# why django can not create a table after deleting the table and the migration files of the app?

Tags: django, django-models, makemigrations

I am working with Django v4.* which I connected it to Postgres DB on the localhost,
I have created my model (Article) then `makemigrations` then `migrate`
then I have changed the model by adding extra field, as a result it didn't take effect so I have deleted the table and all the migrations files in `articles/migrations` folder apart of the `__init__.py` file, then I did `makemigrations` then `migrate` it create a new file `0001_initial.py` but its not creating a new table into the DB, unless I drop the whole DB, which is not ideal in the production env!
I am wondering why Django is unable to create the table back again? and how I can get it created as a new table?

Comment: The migrations table will still have the entry saying that the migration `<your_app>.0001_initial` has been applied. You can mark it as not applied by running the command `python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero --fake`. You can just run `python manage.py migrate <app_name> zero` to delete all the tables via Django instead of manually deleting tables and not have this issue

Answer (score -1):

Roll back to your initial migration by running below command:

`python manage.py migrate --fake <appname> 0001`

Followed by:

`python manage.py migrate <appname>`

Answer (score -2):

Just delete your database with

```
python manage.py flush
```

And delete migrations files

You may have mistyped the directory in the terminal

Comment: The flush command does not delete the database https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#flush

Comment: I think your terminal address is false and flush apply for one another database

Comment: Maybe you mistyped the database variable in the setting.py file